# Over clocking cpu causes a fatal error in the JRE

Tags: java, hardware

I'm attempting to read very large text files (100 gig point cloud files) and my eclipse program read them fine however it was taking awhile. I overclocked my cpu and now I'm getting this fatal error message. It claims " Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows" however I tried to enable them and I still get the message. Any ideas? Here's my file reader class I know its bad code but I doubt that's the issue.

```
public class text_file_reader {

    private volatile String[] data= new String[100000000];
    private volatile int count =0;
    public text_file_reader (String filename) {


        try {

            String line = null;
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(filename);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            int i=0;

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                data [i] = bufferedReader.readLine();
                count++;
                i++;
            }   

            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println( "Unable to open file '" + filename + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + filename + "'");                  
        }
    }

    public String[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't overclock your cpu; you are unlikely to achieve consistent and stable operation (as you have discovered). Basically, if you get *lucky* your cpu is capable of running at the desired voltage, but historically they try and produce cpu(s) capable of stable operation at the highest rating for a given part; the rejects are then sold at the rating they achieve stable operation (so overclocking them is likely to cause subtle errors).

Comment: I was also trying to do 5.5ghz, its weird though every single other application runs fine under stress even cinebench. its only java

Comment: I suggest you test your ram.

Comment: Why the 3d-modelling tag?

Comment: Its a program that reads point cloud files and finds the equations of planes for walls. I use those planes to auto generate walls in Revit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your program appears to be trying to read and buffer a very large file in memory as a huge array of strings.

I suspect that this is generating significant amounts of garbage.  Furthermore, since the amount of reachable data will be growing to tens or hundreds of gigabytes, the GC will be doing a lot of work, and repeatedly accessing pretty much the entire JVM address space.

This kind of this is likely to be stressful for your chipset, especially since you are overclocking it.  It sounds like you have pushed it to the point where you are getting hardware error which are causing the OS to crash.

Solution:

1. Don't overclock your CPU like that.  It is liable to make your system unreliable, and could permanently damage the hardware.
2. Consider modifying your code so that it doesn't need to hold 100,000,000 strings in memory at the same time:

   - Find a more memory efficient representation for your data
   - Change the algorithms so that the data doesn't need to be all in memory at the same time.
   - Or ... just be patient.

---

> I know its bad code but I doubt that's the issue.

On the contrary, I suspect that it is *at the core of the problem*.  At least, I expect that the badness of the code is what is making the system crash for this application and not for cinebench.